# Add private repository to Odoo apps

Tags: git, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I created an account in bitbucket (i think its private). I need to link this repository to Odoo apps.
How can i give odoo's `online-odoo` Github user read access to my repository ?

I referring this [link](https://www.odoo.com/slides/slide/new-odoo-apps-store-how-to-use-it-245/pdf_content).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To publish your Odoo Apps you need to follow steps as below.

- Open your private repository.
- Go to Settings of the repository.
- Click on User and Group Access.
- Go to User section and select "OdooApps" (case sensitive) and give the "Read" rights to this user.

[image]

- After that you need to register your repository inside Odoo App store and scan it. Your private apps are listed inside Odoo App Store.
- Don't forget to use the SSH url of your repository when registering it to identify using ssh. For example for Bitbucket, it would be something like git@bitbucket.org:odoo/odoo#9.0.

For More Details please have a look inside [Apps Upload](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/upload).